Consuming .NET Framework 4.8 OWIN cookie in .NET 8.0 Blazor
I use a .NET Framework 4.8 app as a central auth provider to set a cookie protected by machine key (AES, SHA1).
I want to validate the cookie on my blazor server app which runs on .net 8.0.
I have tried using aspnetTicketBridge. The following code produces ticket as null (without exceptions). The cookieValue is indeed correct. Any suggestions would be helpful.


               string cookieValue = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookieName"];

                string[] test = { "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth", "ApplicationCookie", "v1" };

                
                var ticketDataFormat = new AspNet4TicketDataFormat(
                    new MachineKeyDataProtector("same from machine key config of .net framework"
                    , "same from machine key config of .net framework"
                    , "AES"
                    , "SHA1")
                    .ForPurposes(test)
                    );

                var ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue);



